# Netbeans Maven project: JavaDoc output folder

Tags: java, netbeans, maven, javadoc, documentation-generation

I'm trying to change the JavaDoc output folder of a Maven project I'm developing in Netbeans.

So far I've been able to change it going to *Project Properties* > *Actions*, choosing the actions `Generate JavaDoc` and then setting the property `destDir`.

However, the problem is that the folder structure I'd like to have is this:

```
Root
 '-MavenProject
 '-Javadoc files
```

So I try to set the `destDir` like this:

```
destDir=${project.build.directory}/../../javadoc
```

but it does not work. Looks like the problem is in using `..` to refer to the previous folder, it does not work at all. If I use something like

```
destDir=${project.build.directory}/javadoc
```

it works properly, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Any clues?

Comment: Did you try `${project.directory}` ?

Comment: Yep, but I need to access its parent directory, so it's the same at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to let Maven generate Javadocs in its natural build directory, then copy the result with the [maven-antrun-plugin](http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2009/03/maven-antrun-plugin.html). It understands `/../../`. Of course, you have to have ant installed on you pc...